# RSpec tests failing due to ARGV used instead of .gets

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm building a program that needs to take a number from the user but user will pass it as a parameter in the console when running a program like this: " ruby name_of_program.rb --number 25 " I have used gets.chomp() initially but as it was not collecting the parameter 25 I've changed that quickly to ARGV. All of my RSpec test are failing and I get the following message: TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer. I'm trying to find out why. My program works as intended. How can I get my tests working again ?

```
first_number = 2

given_number = ARGV.last
given_number = given_number.to_i

arr = []

def prime_numbers(first_number, given_number, arr)

  while(first_number <= given_number)
    prime_number = true
    x = 2

    while (x <= first_number / 2)
      if (first_number % x == 0)
        prime_number = false
        break
      end
      x += 1
    end

    if prime_number
      arr << first_number
    end

    first_number += 1
  end

  return arr

end
```

Example test:

```
require 'prime_factors'

RSpec.describe 'prime_factors' do
  let(:array_one) { [2, 3, 5, 7] }
  let(:empty_array) { [] }
  let(:first_number) { 2 }

      context 'prime_numbers function' do

        it 'returns a list of prime numbers for a range 2 - 10 ' do
          given_number = 10
          expect(prime_numbers(first_number, given_number, empty_array)).to eq [2, 3, 5, 7]
        end


    end
    end
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code structure of your app and spec files?

Comment: Hey, I've just edited the post with all the code. If you use .gets (commented out) all the tests will work again. I need to use ARGV though.

Comment: what is your file structure?  You combined app and spec in one file... that can't be right?

Comment: Hey, there are 2 files. prime_factors.rb and prime_factors_spec.rb. First one has 3 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require` this program (what you seem to do), it evaluates `ARGV.last` which returns nil, because ARGV (likely) is an empty array.

I would place the definition of `prime_numbers` into a separate file and require this file in your rspec test.

Comment: Many thanks! I have moved both of my methods to separate files and required them where needed. Do you think is better to wrap them up classes ?

Comment: Technically speaking, every method is in some class, but: Placing methods on top level might cause troubles if the applications gets larger, due to name clashes. Depending on what you want to do with your Prime Numbers, a PrimeNumber class with certain properties might make sense. If you just want to bundle your methods, you could also put them into a Module representing a singleton class (`Module PrimeNumbers; extend self; def YOUR_METHOD1; ...; end; end`).

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer gives you the correct approach, however if you want to test your program using command line args, you would do it like this.  For simplicity I removed flags to command line arguments and just pass 2 numbers but you could modify this if you wanted:

```
#app.rb

first_number = ARGV.first.to_i
given_number = ARGV.last.to_i

arr = []

def prime_numbers(first_number, given_number, arr)

  while(first_number <= given_number)
    prime_number = true
    x = 2

    while (x <= first_number / 2)
      if (first_number % x == 0)
        prime_number = false
        break
      end
      x += 1
    end

    if prime_number
      arr << first_number
    end

    first_number += 1
  end

  return arr

end

print prime_numbers(first_number, given_number, arr)
```

And your spec file

```
#spec/app_spec.rb

RSpec.describe 'prime_factors' do
  let(:exec) { File.expand_path('../app.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__)) }

  describe 'app' do
    it 'returns a list of prime numbers for a range 2 - 10 ' do
      given_number = 10
      res = `ruby #{exec} #{2} #{10}`
      expect(res).to eq '[2, 3, 5, 7]'
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to pass flags in your command line args you can parse the numbers with something like this:

```
args = ARGV.map(&:to_i).select{|arg| arg > 0}

first_number = args.first
given_number = args.last
```

Answer (score 0):

I have split prime_factors.rb into 3 separate files and required them in prime_factors_spec.rb accordingly. Many thanks to you all!